# how to implement logging in django restframework?

Tags: django, python-3.x

When i called  a post call if there are any errors then the errors should be saved in a file and that should be done by using logging how to do that. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, you have to set **`LOGGING`** key in the **`settings.py`** module

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'my_app_name': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Here the **my_app_name** is the name of the app which the `view` containing.

And in your view, initialize a logger as below,

```
import logging
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def my_test_view(request):
    logger.info("This is just test")
    return HttpResponse("Sample HTTPResponse")
```

Comment: its working thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#examples

make following changes

1. `level` should be `WARNING` at all places
2. In `loggers`, use `django.request` instead of `django`
3. You can add `django.server` in `loggers` with same configuration as `django.request` to log errors on local server.

You have to add this code in settings file. Make sure to change `filename` to desired path.

**Please note that I have not tried it. Tell me too if it works.**

Comment: can you please give with an example